# How to use result of built-in function in another function in SASS?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, node-sass, sass-loader

I want to use result of **darken( $var, 10% )** in **oppositeColor( $darkenedColor )** function in SASS.

I have the following code:

```
$color1: #000000 !default;
$color2: darken( $color1, 5% ) !default;
$color3: oppositeColor( $color2 ) !default;
$color4: darken( $color3, 15% ) !default;
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
SassError: $color: oppositeColor(#000000) is not a color.
   ╷
28 │ $color4: darken($color3, 15%) !default;
   │          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there any way I could use result of darken( $color1, 5% ) in oppositeColor( $color2 ) without getting errors?

Comment: Can you share the functions code?

Comment: @Alessandro_Russo They're built-in sass functions.

Comment: Are you sure that oppositeColor it's a built-in sass functions? Can you share the doc link?

Comment: @Alessandro_Russo OMG! I literally checked everything but this! Thank you so much!

Comment: Check my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean `complement`?

I edited the code to creating a working example:

```
$color1: #FFF !default;
$color2: darken( $color1, 5% ) !default;
$color3: complement( $color2 ) !default;
$color4: darken( $color3, 15% ) !default;

.test{
    color: $color4;
}
```

The result is:

```
.test {
  color: #cccccc;
}
```